# No mapping for GET

Tags: java, spring

I usually used xml configs but now want to move on just java config but something is wrong with my code, I dont know what to change because everything seems fine.

Im getting this error after running my spring app on glass fish:

`[glassfish 5.0] [WARNING] [] [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] [tid: _ThreadID=30 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1619543716623] [levelValue: 900] [[ No mapping for GET /spring_project-1.0-SNAPSHOT/home/showHome/]]`

This is my `controller:`

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public class HomeController {
    
        @RequestMapping("/showHome")
        public String showHome() {
    
            return "home";
        }
    }
```

My `view resolver:`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.config")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }
```

}

And `WebAppInitializer:`

```
    public class AppIntializer  implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext =
                new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext =
                new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.register(AppConfig.class);

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
                container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

Comment: As I can see from error, you're trying to access `GET /spring_project-1.0-SNAPSHOT/home/showHome/`. Try checking the path you're accessing, I think it should be just `/home/showHome/`

Comment: Still doesnt work. That path work fine when I create servlet mapping with `web.xml`

Comment: `/home/showHome/` != `/home/showHome`

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the HTTP method in this line.

```
@RequestMapping("/showHome")
```

or just use

```
@GetMapping
```

Also, read the page below it can be useful.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-new-requestmapping-shortcuts